# cl /W4 warns about missing prototype for main

Tags: c, program-entry-point, compiler-warnings, cl

When I use `cl` to compile the *translation unit* that contains `main` and specify the warning level `/W4`, the compiler warns me about the missing function prototype for `main`. Although the compiler is correct that there is no prototype given, I think that it should not warn about this special function because it is fundamental to c, at least when using the standard library.

So, what is the correct approach to handle this in my project if I don't want to give up `/W4`? Do I have to add such a prototype or is there something else to let the compiler know that `main` is sort of a known function?

Comment: How do you declare/define main in your code?

Comment: `int main()`. I now realize that when I define it as `int main(int argc, char *argv[]))` this warning is now ok, however, it is replaced by `warning C4100: 'argv' : unreferenced formal parameter`

Comment: Have you tried `int main(void)` ?

Comment: @WeatherVane I just did and it works perfectly.

Comment: `int main()` is out of date.